failed to start snap.network-manager.networkmanager
Suddenly Ubuntu won't start up and is failing on the line
Failed to start snap.network-manager.networkmanager
How can I find out why it won't start/fix it?

I'd remove the snap version and install the native systemd network-manager.service.  Which Ubuntu version?

@kanehekili How do you do that if "Ubuntu won't start"? It is unlikely that the start up problem is related to snap.network-manager.networkmanager. I'd boot from an Ubuntu USB, and check if the storage device has any errors.

I have checked the filesystem for any errors but all looks fine. Not sure how to change to the native systemd network-manager from the command line.

@Kanehekili. Not sure how to tell the version from the command line. In Grub it is shown as 6.5.0-35.
